# .on for jQuery corner plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the corner plugin in order to get rounded `div`'s. How can I use `.delegate` or `.on` to apply the plugin to `div`'s that will be created in future?

This is what I have to get the rounded corners:

```
$('.myDiv').corner("10px");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not use `.on` or `delegate` for this.

You simply use your same line of code, but you would put it inside whatever function you use to create your new `div`s.

```
......(function() {  // function that creates the new div

   // code that creates your new div called #myNewDiv

   $('#myNewDiv').corner("10px");
});
```

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is used for binding "events" to dynamically created elements and would not work in your situation.  However, for example, if you wanted to bind a `click` event to that new `div`, you'd use `on()`.

`.delegate()` has been superseded by `.on()` [as of jQuery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

Basicaly, .on() is used for attaching event handlers that will be fired also for elements not existing at the time .on() is called.

Your plugin does not work that way - it modifies existing elements, it cannot modify elements that do not exist.

However, if you create your own event, that will be attached handler doing what you mentioned, you will be able to trigger that event on any element you will support. But this is more complex than jus reinitializing your plugin on some elements, as others suggested. Alternatively you can listen to some events that will be probably called after new elements appear (there were some events that were supposed to be called after new element is inserted into the DOM, but you still cannot rely on them - you need to find your site-specific cases or fire your own, preferably namespacedevents after DOM update).

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate new elements, invoke the `corner` method to them.